# unable to register service worker in chrome extension

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to implement the firebase messaging service in Chrome Extension but unable to register the service worker. Please help

Thank you

## Here is my Background.js

```
    var firebaseConfig =
  {
  apiKey: "xx",
  authDomain: "xx",
  databaseURL: "xx",
  projectId: "xx",
  storageBucket: "xx",
  messagingSenderId: "xx",
  appId: "xx",
  measurementId: "xx"
  }

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
  } else {
    console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');
  }
  //firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.usePublicVapidKey("xx");
  
  // WORK WELL
  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function() {
      console.log("=== have permission ===");
      return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(function(currentToken) {
      console.log("Set token : ", currentToken);
      chrome.storage.sync.set({fcmToken: currentToken}, function() {});
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("==== error ====", err);
  });
  
  messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
      messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
          console.log("Refresh token : ", refreshedToken);
          chrome.storage.sync.set({fcmToken: refreshedToken}, function() {});
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
      });
  });
  
  //Never trigger 
  messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "1"});
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  });

});
```

## Here is my manifest.json code

```
{
    "name": "Ticker Chrome Extension",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "description": "Build an Ticker Bar!",
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "identity",
      "identity.email",
      "https://script.google.com/",
      "notifications"
    ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["firebase.js","firebase-app.js","firebase-messaging.js","firebase-messaging-sw.js","background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "image/icon_16.png",
        "48": "image/icon_48.png",
        "128": "image/icon_128.png"
      }
    },
    "icons": {
      "16": "image/icon_16.png",
      "48": "image/icon_48.png",
      "128": "image/icon_128.png"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com; object-src 'self'",  
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/*","Notification/Ding.mp3"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://mail.google.com/mail*"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.4.1.min.js","content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "css": ["style.css"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

==================================================

## Here is my firebase-messaging-sw.js  code

```
[![// importScripts('https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js');
// importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.0/firebase-app.js');
// importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.22.0/firebase-messaging.js');

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx",
    databaseURL: "xx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xx",
    measurementId: "xx"
});
}


const messaging = firebase.messaging();


// NEVER TRIGGER
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('\[firebase-messaging-sw.js\] Received background message ', payload);
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});][1]][1]
```

===============================================
Here is the image of the issue :
[image]

Comment: Remove `"firebase-messaging-sw.js"` from `"background"` in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Thank you, this worked, but when i refreshed the target tab ie Gmail,   i got the error message again.

Comment: It means that you're loading it elsewhere or you're doing something else incorrectly. For example, I don't understand why you're registering it as a service worker in the extension background script where it can only see messages from the extension, but not from tabs. I think you should find an example of using Firebase in an extension and modify it to your needs.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Will you please help me here, in sending firebase push notification via app script.